# 'Make a JavaScript Drum Kit in Vanilla JS! #JavaScript30 1/30' Tutorial keydown event not registering

Tags: javascript, html

I recently started the first project tutorial [Make a JavaScript Drum Kit in Vanilla JS! #JavaScript30 1/30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuN8qwZoego) as a part of the Javascript in 30 Days tutorial series by Wes Bos. I cloned [the repository](https://github.com/wesbos/JavaScript30/tree/master/01%20-%20JavaScript%20Drum%20Kit) off of Github and so I have started with the index-START.html file when I began watching the tutorial.

As he first started making changes to the code at the 3:53 mark, he began inputting code in between the script tags that looked like this:

```
`<script>
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
</script>
`
```

When he ran the code in the chrome browser by typing the "d" key as it is a keyboard drumset, the console reflected that an event had taken place. However, when I had input the exact same code and tried to press the "d" key I received the notification: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: d is not defined at :1:1'.

My questions are this:

(1) Because I am using the Atom code editor which may be different from the code editor used in the tutorial and I have noticed that my script tags are two different colors (my open one is beige and my close one is blue), does the code editor choice have anything to do with my ability to clone this repository correctly, or does it not make a difference? Also does it make a difference if the script tags are two different colors?

(2) What can I do to resolve this so that pressing the alphabetical letters along the 'a' row, which are already defined from the preset code, will result in the 'keydown event' given just the code that is made available from the index-START.html file?

EDIT: all of the code

HTML-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JS Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>


  <div class="keys">
    <div data-key="65" class="key">
      <kbd>A</kbd>
      <span class="sound">clap</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="83" class="key">
      <kbd>S</kbd>
      <span class="sound">hihat</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="68" class="key">
      <kbd>D</kbd>
      <span class="sound">kick</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="70" class="key">
      <kbd>F</kbd>
      <span class="sound">openhat</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="71" class="key">
      <kbd>G</kbd>
      <span class="sound">boom</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="72" class="key">
      <kbd>H</kbd>
      <span class="sound">ride</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="74" class="key">
      <kbd>J</kbd>
      <span class="sound">snare</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="75" class="key">
      <kbd>K</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tom</span>
    </div>
    <div data-key="76" class="key">
      <kbd>L</kbd>
      <span class="sound">tink</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <audio data-key="65" src="sounds/clap.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="83" src="sounds/hihat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="68" src="sounds/kick.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="70" src="sounds/openhat.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="71" src="sounds/boom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="72" src="sounds/ride.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="74" src="sounds/snare.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="75" src="sounds/tom.wav"></audio>
  <audio data-key="76" src="sounds/tink.wav"></audio>

<script>
  window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
  });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  font-family:"Arial", Serif;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

.navbar{
  background-color:#3b5998;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:63px;
}

.navbar a{
  float:left;
  display:block;
  color:#f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar ul{
  margin:8px 0 0 0;
  list-style:none;
}

.navbar a:hover{
  background-color:#ddd;
  color:#000;
}

.side-nav{
  height:100%;
  width:0;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background-color:#111;
  opacity:0.9;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  padding-top:60px;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.side-nav a{
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:22px;
  color: #ccc;
  display:block;
  transition:0.3s;
}

.side-nav a:hover{
  color:#fff;
}

.side-nav .btn-close{
  postion:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:22px;
  font-size:36px;
  margin-left:50px;
}

# main {
  transition:margin-left 0.5s;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:100%;
}

@media(max-width: 568px){
  .navbar-nav{display:none}
}
```

Comment: You have to paste your code.  We can't help you if you don't share what you have.

Comment: Okay, I'll add the full code.

Comment: "*d is not defined*" - are you sure there? You're not using any `d` variable in your code.

Comment: Yeah, it's using the numerical keycode for 'd'. It's one of the numbers. I have the exact same code as the guy running the tutorial and it is working for him.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, I was inputting the letters in the console, not the part of the screen where the events would occur. For this reason, I was receiving the error.